# Etherscan indicates I have tokens, MetaMask cannot find them

Tags: metamask

There are about $2K of Tokens as in the pic, but MetaMask does not get them, and I don't get it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a token to show up in Metamask, the application needs to know that the token contract exists.

Looking in the relevant file in Metamask's GitHub repo ([`contract-map.json`](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-contract-metadata/blob/69550fb739aa6c62069859bd982f2575a7d484f9/contract-map.json)), a mapping for the XYO token hasn't been added. (I doubt adding every airdropped token is something they'd want to do... )

What you can do instead is to add the token to your instance of Metamask manually. There are various guides that'll show you how to do this, including [this](https://one2crypto.com/guides/add-custom-token-metamask/) one.